# combine audio and photo using command line in Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, sound, video, avconv

What is the best way that I can make a video from one photo and one audio file like Mp3

I’m using an Ubuntu headless server, so I need a command line version for this... I tried with `avconv` but I couldn't find any good documentation for it

I used this command but actually it's not what I need because I get something else:

```
 sudo avconv  -i filename_1.png -b:v 1000k test.mp4 -b:a 32k
```

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** Next time, please use your [Shift] key for correct CaPiTaLiSaTiOn!  :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This command will create a video that displays the picture for the duration of the supplied audio file:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i picture.png -i audio.ogg -shortest output.mpeg
```

Add extra goodies as desired.

Comment: ffmpeg  is not working on Ubuntu

Comment: Sure it is -- works just fine for me! :-)    Want to give any more details, like what exactly you mean by "is not working", and perhaps what version of Ubuntu you're running?

Comment: you are right maybe it''s work in your Ubuntu but try to delete it .
you are not able to install it again because there is new version like avconv

Comment: could you give me the installing command ? maybe i did a mistake or some thing like that

Comment: Actually, I didn't have it installed on this machine (fairly new workstation) and I installed it using Synaptic just to answer your question.   I then immediately uninstalled it along with the dependencies that were no longer needed, so I'll install it again here... ffmpeg 7:2.5.7 (This is Ubuntu 15.04). Dependencies are the typical libav*ffmpeg* stuff (most ffmpeg56)  that I see for ffmpeg.    Installed and ran fine.

Comment: When you tried to install, was it complaining that you maybe had conflicting versions of a library?   I've seen problems where something was installed using a different version (e.g. one app wanted a version w/  restricted codecs that another app wanted left out) -- usually from a different repository -- that caused such a conflict.

Comment: Not familiar w/ avconf, but see notes for winff pkg say it's a GUI "for FFmpeg or avconv". Wonder if you have avconv installed (I don't see that pkg available in mine) and it's the conflict. If so, uninstalling it (if you don't need it) might eliminate the conflict and let you install ffmpeg.

Comment: I see in libav-tools pkg (which also uses libav stuff) claims that it "replaces the 'ffmpeg' command-line that was provided in earlier distroreleases".  I see that Installing winff on my system will uninstall ffmpeg to prevent a conflict.

Answer (score 0):

That would do it

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i picture.jpg -i audio.mp3 -shortest -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -tune stillimage output.mp4
```