# Program to encode an audio file to video

Tags: sound, video, youtube, encoding

I need a program to encode an audio file (like wav,mp3,ogg etc) to a video file (with a static picture or black/blank screen)

I want an easy solution were I can achieve that like in a few steps making a few mouse clicks because I am going to need to make lots of those files.

=============================================

## =============tltr=============================

The reason I need to do that is to upload them to my youtube channel and then being able to transcribe them

And I want to use youtube for that since there are only 1 or 2 transcribers for ubuntu that are kinda glitchy and none of them (at least to my knowledge) supports the feature that I most need for such a job

play the audio and then pause it when I start typing (without the need for me to push a button or make a key combo)  and youtube caption editor does exactly that

it also is very easy to accurately timestamp the dialog infact it does it for me almost perfectly and I can find tune with my mouse the minor imperfections to make it 100% perfect.

Its really a shame not being able to find a decent transcription software for linux...

Comment: Have you looked into software for subtitling? Those are probably good for transcription.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) to create a video out of an image and an audio file in terminal. First to install ffmpeg run the following commands in terminal

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

After you get it installed. Run the following command in terminal keeping the image, the audio and the terminal's current directory same:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i <the image file name with extension> -i <the audio file name with extension> -shortest <the output file name>.mpeg
```

for example if your picture file name is image.png and the audio is music.ogg you will run:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.png -i music.ogg -shortest output.mpeg
```

[Similar Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/655371/combine-audio-and-photo-using-command-line-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

Using VLC:
In Media menu, select "convert/save"
In "file selection" clic "add", select your sound file.
Clic "show more option" , clic "play another media synchronously" ,  select your video as "extra media" .
Clic "convert/save" button.
Select "Youtube video SD" in Profile list, give a name as "test.flv" in "file destination"
clic "start",
After transcode process, test.flv  is in your home directory.

Comment: It seems to work I converted and saved a test mp4 (choosed the youtube video SD option) but when I uploaded the video on my channel youtube couldnt process it. I suppose because it has not a picture or something :/

Comment: For me, it works, but treatment in youtube  is quite long (freeze to 95% but it is ok when published)